# What was the present that Shouko gave to Ishida? What did Shouko say after that?

Tags: koe-no-katachi, sign-language

What was the gift that Shouko gave to Ishida? Based on the manga, it’s for decorating plants, but what exactly is it called?

Could it be a marker for flowerbeds or something? Is it something entirely unknown except to the author?

N.B : Does anyone know what did shouko said in panel 2 ?

[image: flowerbeds]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting my whole answer in spoiler as their purpose is explained in chapter 61.

> Those are indeed flower pot decorations. They don't have any specific name, they're usually called [plant pot sticks](http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/plant-pot-sticks), [flower pot sticks](http://www.made-in-china.com/products-search/hot-china-products/Flower_Pot_Stick.html), simply [pot sticks](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/497204081/wine-cork-plant-stick-wine-cork-plant) or something along these lines depending on the website. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3A7N.jpg]

Comment: oh so it has variants name for that

Answer (score 3):

They are Garden Gnomes, just on a stick lol. In Japan they like to make everything all cartoony and cute so they aren't gnomes in Shouko's case, but that's what they are. Here are some pics:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: image 3]

Answer (score 0):

It means  : Good Luck. (and yeah they are decorations on a stick). And she told she loved him, but love and moon is very close of a word in Japan, and since she has a talking disability (because she can't hear herself that well at all) He got confused and tough she said she loved the moon instead of him. And they did bring luck, since he did not die when he fell off that balcony.